# IF logic in jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with following fields:

```
 1. UserType
 2. Username
 3. Password
 4. ConfirmPassord
 5. Description
 6. ContactNumber
 7. Address
```

The form is considered valid when one of the following statements is true:

```
IF Usertype equals to 1
```

then All fields are mandatory

```
IF UserType equals to 2
```

then

```
   1. UserType, 2. Username, 3. Password, 4. ConfirmPassord, 5. Description
```

are mandatory

I know how to require each field and use the other validation methods, but I am trying to figure out an elegant solution to implement the logic I described above. Is a custom method or validation groups the best way to handle this?

Comment: Where is your code?  It would be easier for me to construct a working demo if I had your HTML and JS to base it upon.  Otherwise, I'm doing all the work for you.

Answer (score -1):

you may have to add your own new method for all other fields (2. Username, 3. Password, 4. ConfirmPassord, 5. Description) using `addMethod` to check the value of the userType and then validate or don't validate the other fields.

Comment: Is this solution is most elegant?

Comment: @Anubhav yes, i used it before in similar problem and it works fine, just check for each one the condition of the userType, unfortunately i couldn't find the code, it was for my previous company.